# Why cannot I paste codes generated from dust website directly?

Tags: dust.js

Now I wrote a template very easily:

```
Hello, my name is {name}, I'm {age}.
```

And then open this website: http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html, do some pasting and the template js codes are generated below:

```
(function() {
  dust.register("demo", body_0);

  function body_0(chk, ctx) {
    return chk.write("Hello, my name is ").reference(ctx._get(false, ["name"]), ctx, "h").write(", I'm ").reference(ctx._get(false, ["age"]), ctx, "h").write(".");
  }
  return body_0;
})();
```

Then I created a js file and copy all the js codes generated above and refer this into my app:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>DustDemo</title>
    <script src="jsfiles/dust.js"></script>
    <script src="jsfiles/staticpagetemplate.js"></script>

    <script>
        function Demo1() {
            dust.render("demo", { name: "test", age: 13 }, function (err, out) {
                alert(out);
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="Demo1()">
    <h1>Demo 1——Static Page</h1>
    <div id="divDemo1">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Question is that if I use like this, it reports me "_get" cannot be found. Later I found the problem in dust.js:

```
Context.prototype.get = function (key) {
        var ctx = this.stack, value;

        while (ctx) {
            if (ctx.isObject) {
                value = ctx.head[key];
                if (!(value === undefined)) {
                    return value;
                }
            }
            ctx = ctx.tail;
        }
        return this.global ? this.global[key] : undefined;
    };
```

So no "_get" but "get" instead!

**Why this MISMATCHES the translator online?? Anyone can help me??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are likely using an old version of Dust in `jsfiles/dust.js`. As of Dust 2.2.0 `get` has been replaced with `_get`. The compiler on http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html uses the new version of Dust, so it compiles the template using `_get` instead of `get`.

You have compiled your template with a new version of Dust, but you are trying to render it with an old version of Dust, and the two are not compatible.

Comment: Any notices about this on the dust GitHub? Many thanks!

Comment: The change is backward compatible if your templates were compiled with the Dust < 2.2.0 and try to render them with Dust >= 2.2.0, however we didn't foresee the desire to compile templates with Dust >= 2.2.0 and then render them with Dust < 2.2.0. As such, there was only a passing mention on http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/

Comment: Many many thanks! In order to help others I'd also share two on-line links:

1) 2.2.0 (Below): http://akdubya.github.io/dustjs/

2) 2.2.0 (or above): http://linkedin.github.io/dustjs/test/test.html